# How to find in which overlay is desired package?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, repository

How do I identify which overlays (if any) contain a particular package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was just looking for the very same thing. If you use `eix`, you are in luck.

From the wiki:

#### Adding overlays to the cache

To search not only in the portage tree but all the overlays, add overlays to the cache

```
root # eix-remote update
```

and then sync it all:

```
root # eix-sync
```

(example from my system)

```
 $ eix nuvola
* x11-themes/nuvola
  Available versions:  1.0-r1^bs
  Homepage:            http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=5358
  Description:         Nuvola SVG icon theme
```

Hmm that doesn't look like a google music player ... time to add some more sources:

```
 $ eix-remote update
<snip>
Saving to: 'eix-cache.tbz2'
* Unpacking data
layman/Armageddon -> Armageddon
layman/AstroFloyd -> AstroFloyd
 layman/AzP -> AzP
<snip>
```

looks like about 500 sources :)

```
root # eix-sync -q
```

Now when searching, if you wish to expand your search, add -R (remote) to search all overlays, installed or not. You will want to sync it with `eix-remote` from time to time. See `man eix`.

```
 $ eix -R nuvola
* media-sound/nuvolaplayer
 Available versions:  (~)2.0.1[2] (~)2.0.3[1] {debug}
 Homepage:            https://launchpad.net/nuvola-player
 Description:         Cloud music integration for your Linux desktop

* x11-themes/nuvola
 Available versions:  1.0-r1^bs
 Homepage:            http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=5358
 Description:         Nuvola SVG icon theme

[1] "sabayon" layman/sabayon
[2] "tante" layman/tante
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an automated system to search through overlayes by specific package name. what you can do is:

- run `layman -L` to see the available overlays and guess based on their names if they have the package you are looking for.
- search here: http://gpo.zugaina.org/
- google for 'gentoo package_name'

Comment: Looks like you are right. I tried Paludis with `cave show <package-name>` which can show package's repository, but it searches only in overlays already added to `layman` AFAIK.
 I'll wait 2 days to accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not before, but during emerging you will see:

[image: gentoo emerge from Guru]

Answer (score -1):

Emerge will tell you the name of the repository if you pass -v

Comment: Looks like no :( 

```# emerge --search --verbose aws-vault
  
[ Results for search key : aws-vault ]
Searching...

*  app-admin/aws-vault
      Latest version available: 6.6.0
      Latest version installed: 6.6.0
      Size of files: 15012 KiB
      Homepage:      https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault
      Description:   Securely store and access AWS credentials in development environments
      License:       Apache-2.0 BSD BSD-2 MIT

[ Applications found : 1 ]
```